# Modelica Modification by Extension/Inheritance

Tags: extends, modelica, openmodelica

I would like to change the name and the description of a parameter/variable while inheriting another model on OpenModelica.

I tried to do it by using replaceable/redeclare properties of Modelica language but it didn't work out. So far I am doing as below, but as you can see, it is not a good practice.

```
model MySubModel
  Real myVar "Some general description"
  parameter Real myParam "Some general description" 
eqaution
  der(myVar) = myParam*time; 
end MySubModel

model MyModel
  extends MySubModel(myParam=Coeff);
  Real TimeIntegral "Integral of time, just nonsense"
  parameter Real Coeff = 12 "Coefficient bla bla"
equation
  MyVar = TimeIntegral
end MyModel
```

The important point for me is that the description of variables and parameters must be given individually while inheriting because I will export the model as .fmu and the description carries all necessary information for me such as unit, reference, explanation etc.

Answer (score 4):

I don't see a better way in standard Modelica if you want to rename variables/parameters, change descriptions and values.

The real problem is changing the name.

If you are content with only changing descriptions (and values) the following is correct according to the specification - but it is not guaranteed that the changed descriptions will be used (it works in Dymola - I have not tested in OpenModelica), and it does not look nice:

```
model MySubModel
  Real myVar "Some general description";
  parameter Real myParam "Some general description";
equation
  der(myVar) = myParam*time; 
end MySubModel;

model MyModel
  extends MySubModel(redeclare parameter Real myParam=12 "Coefficient",
       redeclare Real myVar "Integral of time, just nonsense");
end MyModel;
```

(Note that this is a redeclaration of a non-replaceable element and according to 7.3.3 of the specification it must have the same type as the original declaration.)

Comment: Actually, I was accepting this solution to work as I had read something similar to it, though without using redeclare. I tried it now and it didn't work for OpenModelica. In fact, the value isn't set at all. When I use only the following:
extends MySubModel(myParam=12 "Coefficient")
Then the value is set but the description stays same. I tried both methods also with no initial description in the base model. It didn't help either.

Another solution might have been, according to [chapter 7.2.4](https://www.modelica.org/documents/ModelicaSpec33.pdf). It doesn't work.